# View TypeScript dependencies' source in IDE

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I've recently moved from a Java company to a TypeScript one, and am getting to grips with the tooling. In IntelliJ, I'm accustomed to being able to Command-Click a method declaration to be taken to the source code. However, in TypeScript, unless the package is checked out locally, I seem to only be able to see the `.d.ts` and `.js` files - no `.ts` to be found (including when checking manually in `node_modules`). Is there a way to directly view the source of a dependency TypeScript package in IntelliJ (or, failing that, some other IDE)?

(Yes, I know - in an ideal world, I wouldn't need to view the actual source, because the method signature and the documentation should be sufficient for me to reason against an external contract. How often do we live in an ideal world? :) )

Comment: I'm using VSCode, it works and even allow me to peek and edit the code in a small window.

Comment: are the original `.ts` file included in the module distribution (i.e. are they available locally after installing a module with `npm i`)?

Comment: No - which makes me suspect that there's no way to do what I'm aiming to do (as I believe that the `.ts` -> `.js` compilation process is not reversible, since it erases type information) - but I wanted to check with those who know more about TypeScript than I do.